# How to upload sound to a question?

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

Assume you want to ask to identify an excerpt of music you've recorded or recreated with some software. Is there a way to add it to the question in a similar way as an image, so that one does not need to upload it somewhere else, risking dead links sooner or later?

Comment: No, and it would be incredibly hard to moderate if it's added.

Answer (score 6):

There's no built-in Stack Exchange solution for this; unlike images, from which almost all sites profit at some point, sound snippets are only useful for specific websites. (Oh, and the built-in solution for images uses imgur.com, an external hoster too.)

According to the answer to [What site-specific post formatting settings are available?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298843/295232), three sites in the network ([Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3616/could-we-get-the-audio-embedding-feature-for-ppcg), [Music Practice & Theory](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245/youtube-and-soundcloud-embedding-is-now-enabled), [Video Production](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190/youtube-and-soundcloud-embedding-is-now-enabled)) have the option to embed sound/music which has been uploaded to [SoundCloud](http://soundcloud.com/). It's a feature which would be useful for this site as well; it [has been requested](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32/3189) but from some tests it looks only the YouTube embedding has been added. Perhaps it's time to ask for SoundCloud embedding as well?

Comment: SoundCloud embedding [was enabled on this site](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32/requesting-automatic-embedding-of-youtube-and-soundcloud-links) as well as MP&T; however, it's been [broken on the latter site](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3643/soundcloud-embedding-new-issues) since at least Jan 21, 2021.

Comment: (I assume [status-completed] means in was implemented....)

Comment: @Aaron well, [the answer by a staff member](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/a/693/3189) only talks about YouTube. I doubt SoundCloud has ever worked here (see also the comment).